# How to load a django contrib app without modifying directly the templates of the project

Tags: python, django

I have built a django app, which when enabled (from the settings.py), can be accessed by the main menu of the project. 
In order to check if the app is enabled, I use this snippet in one of the templates:

```
{% if 'my_project.contrib.edit_app' in INSTALLED_APPS %}
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-xs" href="{% url "display_data" resource.service_typename %}">{% trans "Edit App" %}</a>
{% elif 'my_project.contrib.edit_data' not in INSTALLED_APPS %}
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-xs" href="{% url "new_app" %}?layer={{resource.service_typename}}&storeType={{resource.storeType}}">{% trans "New App" %}</a>
            {% endif %}
```

Apparently is not a good practice to "leak" into the core code, code of contrib apps. 
What would be a good method to delegate this to the application itself?

Comment: Use template tags instead of doing all that logic in the template.

Comment: @bobort do you have an example in mind of something similar?